# Modify constructor parameter at the base class before processing at the inhertiting class

Tags: c#, inheritance

My program generates specific messages which contain several fields. I need to restore the message from string where each field is represented as a new line. There is a class (`MailServiceContent`) with logic for main fields and other classes (in the example: `SendMailServiceContent`) containing logic for other fields. 
The whole process of restoring messages I imagine in the following way: the base constructor processes the main fields from the string (the number of main fields lines isn't constant, it can be 3 or 4), next the concrete constructor (in the example constructor of `SendMailServiceContent`) process further lines. Is it possible that the concrete constructor get the parameter string data with truncated main field lines so it can process it's part? Or meaby there is another "good" way to handle this situation besides making a method at the base class that will return number of processed lines and ommiting the lines at the concrete class (which will be problematic in "deeper" inheritance)

```
class MailServiceContent
{
    ...
    public enum Message_Type
    {
        SEND_MAIL = 1,
        RECEIVE_MAIL = 2,
        RECEIVE_MAIL_PERIODIC = 3,
        UNREGISTER_USER = 4,
        RESPONSE_WITH_USER_ID = 5,
        RESPONSE = 6
    };

    public MailServiceContent(string data){
        //restore main part from string
    }

    public static MailServiceContent Create(byte[] data){
        string decodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        Message_Type messageType;

        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(decodedData))
        {
            messageType = (Message_Type)int.Parse(stringReader.ReadLine());
        }

        switch (messageType)
        {
            case Message_Type.SEND_MAIL:
                return new SendMailServiceContent(decodedData);
            case Message_Type.RECEIVE_MAIL_PERIODIC:
                return new PeriodicReceiveMailServiceContent(decodedData);
            case Message_Type.RESPONSE_WITH_USER_ID:
                return new ResponseMailServiceContent(decodedData);
            case Message_Type.RESPONSE:
                return new ResponseWithIDMailServiceContent(decodedData);
            default:
                return new MailServiceContent(decodedData);
        }
    }
}

class SendMailServiceContent: MailServiceContent
{
    ...
    public SendMailServiceContent(string data):base(data){
        //restore further part from string
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the point of why are doing this in the constructor, yes of course this is possible. You simply have some logic in your base class, and then you have more logic in the inheriting class. They will each do their portion of the work. For example, here is a simple application. It starts with 4 string in a list which is passed to `B`. `B` inherits `A`. Therefore, `A` will do some work first: Add 5 to the list. Then `B` will do some work: Add 6 to the list. At the end you will have 6 items in the list.

```
class Program {

   static void Main(string[] args) {
         var items = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
         B b = new B( items);
         foreach( var item in items ) {
            Console.WriteLine( item );
         }
         Console.Read();
   }
}

public class A {
   public A(List<string> data) {
      data.Add( "5" );
   }
}

public class B : A {
   public B(List<string> data) : base(data) {
      data.Add( "6" );
   }
}
```

What the constructor does is based on your code. If you only want to do part of the processing, then only write code for that part.

Comment: I dont see any other solution then using constructor in this case. Assuming that instead we have method `Parse(string data)` that will process appropriate field lines from the string at all level of inheritance ,`Parse` method at inheriting class would  call `Parse` method from base class which in turn don't know on which inheriting class instance it should set the appropriate  fields.

Comment: Ok so I see that it comes to just simple modifying the reference at the base constructor.

Comment: Are you asking me another question or does that answer your question?